# executing webapi functions on client machine(Access db of the client system)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, client-server, bloomberg

i've created a project(asp.net) - website

The database resides on the client machine.

Flow:
Client opens the website, and submit with the required fields, and then the server would authenticate.
Next, the api what i've created should be transferred to the Client pc, as the database would be accessible only where the client and server at the same system only.
Limitation: cannot move the database to the server, ie making database on the server.

If i'm hosting website on the localhost, everything is running fine, and also m fetching data from the database and i can see it on the browser.
But the same if i'm hosting website on server, m not able to fetch any result.

Is there any method or so, to execute on the client system that would be making connection between the cient browser and database residing on the client system only.

The whole scenario is same as of: bloomberg (what i came to knw about my issue and the bloomberg as a public db to be used issue), where bbg restricts its usage on the web, and bbg is accessble only for the client system for the client n on that client account only.

ON STRAIGHT: is it possible to access the client machine database or an application  by browser.
Because i after making opening the website and also making some input and then submit, the call should call api which will access the data to be shown on browser would be from the client pc.(lets say - database resides at client pc)

Comment: Please, re-estate the answer in a more clear way, or so some code, and give concrete details of the DB, the API, teh server, and so on.

Comment: we have not yet codded in that particular way, its a conceptual view regarding whether it can be achieved or  not. my question relies on  is it possible to run the database api on the client machine, as the database is there on the client machine.
Database: any (*Bloomberg)
API on platform : PHP (*OR ASP.NET)
API to access bloomberg is on .net

Comment: Your question qwill be soon closed as "Unclerar what you asked" if you don't edit it. I don't mind, but if you ask something that can be understood you'll most probably get an answer

Comment: @JotaBe i've edited (please check the last point. which may help you. if not, then whole of the process will be stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to access a traditional database on a PC directly from the browser. You'd need a web app in the middle, so that your browser accesses the web app, and this offers indirect access to the database.

If you can install a web app that has access to the PC database, there are interesting ASP.NET and browser technologies to access the data: [Web API OData](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api) + [breeeze.js](http://learn.breezejs.com/).

The only alternative would be to use HTML5 Storage databases, but they are still under definition and mostly unsupported. See, for example, this page: [HTML5 Features: Storage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage). An this is not what you're looking for.